# Cross compile for arm& linux on windows machine

Tags: linux, arm, toolchain

I need to cross build application in **Windows** for **ARM and Linux machine**.

Suprsingly, I didn't find a toolchain for windows,

Is there such a toolchain or did I miss somthing in my understanding ?

Thank you,
ranran

Comment: Off topic, but yes, you can definitely get such a thing. https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads

Comment: @CarlNorum that's for bare metal target, not for Linux

Comment: Thanks, I did found that link before, but it only for arm, not linux. I don't think it includes pthreads for example.

Comment: Microsoft provides an ARM compiler, linker and assembler. Their documentation sucks, but the tools are available. You only need to open an ARM Developer Command Prompt. Also see [cryptest.nmake](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.nmake) for an example of an Nmake file to drive compile and link.

Answer (score 2):

Here https://www.linaro.org/downloads/

scroll down to "Latest Linux Targeted Binary Toolchain Releases"

Comment: which of this binary is for windows: https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-linux-gnueabihf/

Comment: *"Both x86_64 Linux and Mingw32 (MS Windows compatible) host binaries are provided"* so it should be the one with `mingw32` in the archive filename.

Comment: I tried now, it but it has static link and windows complains (readonly file systzem...")

Comment: Any idea how to extract tar.xz in windows ?