# How can I cross compile an arm linux target project on windows?

Tags: linux, windows, arm, embedded-linux

I want to use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc on windows.

How can I get this toolchain to work on my windows 10 OS?

Comment: I have solved the issue. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850543/cross-compile-for-arm-linux-on-windows-machine was helpful.